# Reading the content of an attached property outside the UI thread

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties

**CONTEXT**

I have a complex WPF application and I'm building a tooling system aimed to clean up the XAML files and make sure they respect business rules for styling and localization. In order to do so, I'm loading the proper dependencies.

```
Assembly.LoadFrom(Path.Combine(assemblieLocation, "SomeAssembly" + ".dll"));
```

Once loaded, I create my proper instances through Reflection

```
(UIElement)Activator.CreateInstance(typeToInstantiate, true);
```

**PROBLEM**

The problem I'm having is to be able to read the content from an [attached property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/attached-properties-overview). In the context I'm in right now, the WPF application uses either the Text property of a TextBlock or a custom dependency property defined internally. Knowing that dependency properties must define the Get/Set pair in order to access the content of the property and make sure the CLR can make know for sure that there's a difference between the custom property and the one that could come directly from .NET or an lib, that's the approach I followed.

```
if(uiElemetInstance is TextBlock tBlock && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(CustomClass.GetText(tBlock))
```

The problem that I have here is at runtime, even though, in the XAML file, Text is defined with a value, my system can instantiate without a problem the TextBlock but cannot see the contents of the Text property; it remains as an empty string and I cannot figure out why that is.

**REPRODUCIBLE STEPS**

Required elements

1. 1 Console app
2. 1 WPF application
3. 1 XAML file
4. Define a custom class that will define the attach property (defined in the WPF project)
5. Using Reflection to load WPF project in console app
6. Read the attach property content from the console app

Here's a link to my [gist](https://gist.github.com/Kavignon/967d41b1ab6b6f51aa62cc7e89b9773b) that contains all the requirements of this issue.

Comment: Why don't you just do; `!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tBlock.Text)`?. `tBlock.Text` will get you the current value of the `Text` property if that's what you want.

Comment: I failed to mentioned that even the Text property of the UI element remains also an empty string even though it is well defined in the XAML file @mm8 (I will update my question so others will know)

Comment: It it returns an empty string, it means that it has not been set to any other value.

Comment: @mm8 in the XAML file I'm currently analyzing, in the definition of the TextBlock, the Text property is defined through class defined internally. Something such as <TextBlock CustomClass.Text="SomeTextValue" />

Comment: You should include a reproducible sample of your issue if you want someone to be able to help you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Please see edits @mm8